# Write structure to a binary file, read it from file, store in buffer, print the buffer

Tags: c, file, binaryfiles

I am trying to write a structure to a binary file, the punctuation will be received as a parameter in the `insertInFile` function, (working with raspberryPi, and store the values of the time reaction with switches). Then I want to read from the file and and store the values on the heap and finally read those values I stored dynamically. I'm having problems with this because either it cannot read properly or it cannot write to the binary file.

```
typedef enum dificulty {
    EASY, MEDIUM, HARD
} Dificulty;
typedef struct player {
    char nickname[MAXSIZE];
    enum dificulty Dificulty;
    float pontuacion;
} Player;

#define LED_CYCLES 5
#define MAX_PLAYERS 2

int insertInFile(float const *const timeReceived, unsigned short *level, char *playerName) {
    Player players[MAX_PLAYERS];
    int count = 0, i;
    FILE *fplayers;

    //check if file can be opened
    if ((fplayers = fopen("game.bin", "wb")) == NULL) {
        fputs("Erro ao abrir ficheiro\n", stderror);
        return (-1);
    }
    //go to the beginning of the file
    rewind(fplayers);

    //cycle that allows to save int the bin file the struct "Player"
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        Player[i].pontuacion = &timeReceived[count];
        Player[i].Dificulty = &level;
        Player[i].nickname = &playerName;
        fwrite(&players, sizeof (Player), count, fplayers);
    }

    //close the bin file
    fclose(fplayers);

    return 0;
}

void obtainFromFile() {
    Player players;
    int count = 0;
    FILE *fplayers;
    size_t size;
    unsigned char *buffer;
    int i;

    //open file
    fp = fopen("game.bin", "rb");
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(fp);        // calculate the size needed
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    buffer = (unsigned char *)malloc(size);

    if (fplayers == NULL) {  // check some error if file == empty
        printf("Error\n", stderr);
        return (-1);
    } else
    if (fread(&buffer, sizeof (*buffer), size, fp) != size) // if count of read bytes != calculated size of .bin file -> ERROR
        printf("Error\n", stderr);
        return (-1);
    } else {
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            printf("%02x", buffer[i]);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    free(buffer);
}
```

Comment: in `insertInFile` there is `count = 0`and then `for (i = 0; i < count; i++)` ==> this loop should never be entered. Also, the variable `Player` is an array, so it should be indexed: `Player.pontuacion = ` ==> `Player[i].pontuacion = ` etc etc.

Comment: @CharlesLiuChina you are saying i used fwrite and fread in the wrong place or that the parameters in between () are  wrong?

Comment: There is about a zillion compilation errors here. Is this your real up-to-date code?

Answer (score 1):

In `insertInFile()` there is a misunderstanding of the structure use. Writing `Player.pontuacion` is not right.

> To assign a value in an array of struct `Player
>   players[MAX_PLAYERS];`, use `players[i].Dificulty = (Dificulty)level`.

```
//cicle that allows to save int the bin file the struct "Player"
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    players[i].pontuacion = timeReceived[count];
    players[i].Dificulty = (Dificulty)(level[count]);
    strncpy(players[i].nickname,playerName,MAXSIZE-1);
    players[i].nickname[MAXSIZE]='\0';
}
// write count players
fwrite(&(players[0]), sizeof (Player), count, fplayers);
```

Instead of:

```
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    Player.pontuacion = &timeReceived[count];
    Player.Dificulty = &level;
    Player.nickname = &playerName;
    fwrite(&players, sizeof (Player), count, fplayers);
}
```

Comment: `players[i].nickname[MAXSIZE]='\0';` writes beyond the end of `nickname`. Do not use `strncpy()`, it is confusing and error prone, even when used correctly, it manages to attract bugs.  Use `snprintf(players[i].nickname, sizeof(players[i].nickname), "%s", playerName);` and initialize the array to all bits zero with `memset` to avoid writing garbage values to the binary file.

Comment: I have used `strncpy()` instead of `strcpy()` just to highlight that `nickname` is allocated to a fixed size (needed to write a fixed size of the Player structure).

Comment: @J.Piquart: I am aware of that. `strcpy()` could cause a buffer overflow, but `strncpy()` is the wrong fix for this problem because of its widely misunderstood semantics, which would indeed be almost appropriate in this particular case, but still caused a bug in your code, and will cause more problems for less savvy programmers.

Comment: @chqrlie, sorry, but the code `snprintf(players[i].nickname, sizeof(players[i].nickname), "%s", playerName);` doesn't truncate to `MAXSIZE` as expected (no place for the `'\0'` terminator). Should be `snprintf(players[i].nickname, sizeof(players[i].nickname)-1, "%s", playerName);`

Comment: on the contrary, `snprintf` **does** truncate its output to make it a properly null terminated string within the boundaries of the destination buffer whose size is provided. It does not write to the destination buffer if passed a size of 0.  This is consistent with `fgets()` and `scanf_s()`.  On the other hand, `strncpy()` is the bad guy with counterintuitive semantics take make it error prone.